# Retrieving value from C# combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I am currently having a hard time to retrieve the value from a combobox in C#.
The combobox items are populated from a database.
This is how I fill the items:

```
while (reader.Read())

                {
                    ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
                    item.Text = (string)reader[0];
                    item.Value = (string)reader[1];
                    comboBox8.Items.Add(item);

                }
```

This command show the Text, but not the value:

```
String s = comboBox8.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

and this command throws a "System.NullReferenceException"

```
String s = comboBox8.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: possibly reader[1] returns NULL value for some iteration

Comment: Well, my questions is - how to get the value of the entry!

Comment: @Manish Mishra No, it does not return NULL.

Comment: if (comboBox8.SelectedValue == null)
{
    return;
}
string value = comboBox8.SelectedValue.ToString();  //it don't matter if you use [reader.GetString("Id")] just better way [if you know, it is String representation in db]

Comment: hey what is this comboboxItem? is it your own class?

Comment: @ManishMishra http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem.aspx

Comment: is it not winforms? what is it then? silverlight?

Comment: If it is WinForms, what type of DropDownStyle are you using? if you want to have a combo box the provides only a list then you should set the dropdown style to "DropDownList" this forces the combo box to show a read only list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SelectedValue property is used when you have linked the ComboBox to a data source, and want to return a value other than what is displayed.

For example, one alternative may be to create a DataTable, put your database readings into there, and assign the combobox selected value and text there. For example;

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
//column 1 name, which will be display member
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("nameOfYourTextField"); 
//column 2 name, which will be your value member
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("nameOfYourValueField"); 

//assign your datasource (the datatable) to the combobox
comboBox8.DataSource = dataTable; 

//and finally assign your value member (the text you want returning)
comboBox8.ValueMember = "nameOfYourValueField";
//and your display member (the text visible in the combobox)
comboBox8.DisplayMember = "nameOfYourTextField";
```

Then in your reader;

```
while (reader.Read())

            { 
                //create a new row which matches the signature of your datatable
                DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
                //assign data to the rows, given a certain column name
                row["nameOfYourValueField"] = reader[1];
                row["nameOfYourTextField"] = reader[0];
                //and add the row to the datatable
                dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

            }
```

Comment: No problem  : ) Give me a shout if you run into any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `SelectedItem` property of combobox

```
var selectedItem =  comboBox8.SelectedItem  as ComboboxItem;
if (selectedItem != null)
{
    // Do something with the selectedItem.Value or selectedItem.Text
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work. The strange thing is, when I try this, I get the Value: while (reader.Read()) { ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem(); item.Text = (string)reader[0]; item.Value = (string)reader[1]; comboBox8.Items.Add(item);String s = item.Value.ToString(); }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method too.

After binding combobox, you have to set:

```
 comboBox8.ValueMember = "DBFieldName1";
 comboBox8.DisplayMember = "DBFieldName2";

 if(comboBox8.SelectedItem != null)
 {
        string text=comboBox8.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string value=comboBox8.SelectedValue.ToString();
 }
```

**Note :**-Also make sure the reader not returns any null value or repeated values.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This throws the System.NullReferenceException for "string value"

Comment: Then reader must have returns any null value to  item.Value = (string)reader[1];  Please check your database values

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check.. you have to set value member and display member properties too.

Comment: Still not working but thanks anyways for your effort! I accepted another answer as it is working.